# Is there any way to move the itunes files (not just the music library) to another folder?

Tags: itunes, windows

I'm running iTunes on Windows 10 and I'm trying to move the iTunes folder out of the root of my music folder. I want that folder to have only music.

All I can find is instructions on how to move the 'iTunes Media' folder from "Music\iTunes\iTunes Media" to another spot. **I want to move the whole iTunes folder, including .itl and .itdb files.**

Comment: I believe some people have reported this doesn't work - not able to test due to lack of suitable OS - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73563/moving-the-itunes-library-to-the-data-partition

Comment: Closing as dupe - but please edit this if you're situation is different than the post that's unanswered. An edit there might help bump it to the home page or a bounty.